# Show related fields from different models in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have following 3 models in Django. We have multiple `Grades`. Each `Grade` has multiple `subjects`. Each `subject` has multiple `lessons`.

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Subject(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='subject')

class Lesson(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='lesson')
```

In my admin console when I am trying to add a new `Lesson` , I only see a `Subject` dropdown. Multiple grades can have the same subject name. eg: grade 1 has subject english and grade 2 has subject english.

Hence I would like to see both `grade` & `subject` dropdown in my `Lesson` model in admin console.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to have one admin page to create `Grade`, `Subject`, and `Lesson` objects. However, Django doesn't support nested inline with Foreign Keys. One relations which span more than one levels. You have a few options.

You can change the `Lesson` model, so that it has a direct FK to `Grade` and `Subject` something like this:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='lesson_subject')
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='lesson_grade')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.grade = self.grade.grade
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can attach `LessonInline` to `GradeAdmin`, and get a kind of nested inline.

Alternatively, there are a few third party Django apps which allow nested inline. A quick Github or DjangoPackages search will find one which suits your needs and tastes.

Answer (score 0):

[django-nested-admin](https://pypi.org/project/django-nested-admin/) is a great package for showing nested models in the admin console. Its not very pretty but gets the job done and saves a lot of overhead.

Good [Article](https://www.bedjango.com/blog/how-use-django-nested-admin/) that details on how to use this package.

My [Github](https://github.com/aseem-hegshetye/Learning-Django/tree/master/admin_nested) repository containing django project demonstrating the usage of django-nested-admin package.